# Сослагательное, условное и желательное наклонение

Tags: наклонение

"Русская грамматика" (почти 40 лет) разделяет ***сослагательное,*** **условное** и ***желательное*** наклонения, хотя они все строятся на базе частицы "бы" и глагола в прошедшем времени. В испанском языке есть отдельная категория "кондиционал", и глагол в этой категории имеет свои собственные формы.

У меня вопрос: можно ли выделять условное и желательное наклонение в отдельное наклонение, если эти наклонения не имеют собственной морфологической формы?
Или в современном русском языке уже нет этого отличия?
Большое спасибо!

Comment: В лингвистике нет понятия "мой язык". Есть английский, испанский, чешский... финский, наконец. Если вам важно провести какие-то параллели, назовите "ваш". Если нет, зачем вообще упоминать?

Comment: Вы правы, извините! я упомянула испанский язык потому что наши грамматики отделяют его как отдельное наклонение из-за наличия собственных форм глагола (он соответствует русскому условному н.) сейчас исправлю

Comment: Вот, к сожалению, испанский - не моя  стихия.  Ну сейчас попробую посмотреть грамматику, может, что-то и прояснится. Но вообще-то суть от этого не изменится. Формы могут совпадать, но наклонения быть разными. Бывает и наоборот, одна грамматическая категория может выражаться разными формами, прямой связи нет. А главное тут то, что единой, общепринятой модели грамматики в естественных  языках нет и быть не может.  Поэтому "выделять" можно всё, что не противоречит остальному. Выделение отдельного "желательного" наклонения не противоречит ничему, более того оно реально в русском существует.

Comment: Это конструкции с частицей ка, типа "Дай-ка я сделаю", "Пойди-ка ты в дом". Достаточно естественно конструкции с тождественной семантической нагрузкой считать тем же наклонением. Остальное все - в ответе.

Comment: I'm confused потому что иногда читаю, что "условное РАНьШЕ называлось сосл.накл." (получается это одно и то же наклонение?), а другие источники рассматривают его абсолютно отдельно :S uffff

Comment: Отвечу сейчас в тексте.

Comment: @Anonym, вы имеете в виду Академическую грамматику-80?

Comment: Серж: я говорила про "русская грамматика" (автор Шведова)

Answer (score 4):

На базе частицы БЫ строится одно наклонение – сослагательное, но оно имеет разные оттенки значений, в том числе желательное и условное.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

**1) Три наклонения**

**В грамматике русского языка существуют три наклонения**: **изъявительное** (выражает реальность действия), **повелительное** (выражает требуемость действия, побуждение к действию) и **сослагательное** (указывает на ирреальность действия, его возможность, предположительность).

**2) Форма** (использован материал из Грамматики-80)

**Сослагательное наклонение  строится на базе частицы БЫ,** при этом оно имеет одну основную форму: глагол в форме прошедшего времени + частица БЫ. Дополнительно:  (1) Частица БЫ может также входить в состав союза ЧТОБЫ, ЕСЛИ БЫ. (2) Частица БЫ может выражать сослагательное наклонение **одна или с инфинитивом**: Кваску бы сейчас! Попить бы кваску!

**3) Значение** (классификация взята из учебник Розенталя)

Сослагательное наклонение **имеет несколько значений**: (1) зависимость от внешних причин (условность), (2) желательность, (3) совет (приказ, просьба) в более мягкой или более жесткой форме.

**Примеры:**

**(1) Условность.**  Если бы ты не помог мне, я не смог бы добраться домой. Без твоей помощи я не добрался бы домой. Если бы не было дождя, мы пошли бы гулять.

**(2)  Желательность.** Почитал бы я сейчас хорошую книгу. Поехала бы я домой.  Ехал бы лучше завтра. **В форме инфинитива:** Поехать бы домой! Отдохнуть бы немного! Домой бы сейчас!

**(3) Совет, просьба.** Проводили бы вы нас домой (вместо: проводите нас домой). Чтобы завтра работа была сделана!

**4) Одно наклонение в значении другого**

Приди ты на час раньше, ничего бы не случилось (если бы ты пришел..). Повелительное наклонение в роли сослагательного.

Помирился бы ты с ним (помирись с ним). Желательное значение сослагательного наклонения.

Answer (score 3):

> У меня вопрос: можно ли выделять условное и желательное наклонение в
>   отдельное наклонение, если эти наклонения не имеют собственной
>   морфологической формы?

Можно. А почему нельзя и причем тут собственная форма? В английском вообще специальных "форм" нет, а наклонения есть.

> Или в современном русском языке уже нет этого отличия?

Какого отличия? Семантическое отличие безусловно есть. Грамматическое - на уровне синтаксиса всей фразы тоже присутствует, но если вы не владеете базовой грамматикой русского, говорить об этом бесполезно, надо хотя бы ваш уровень понять.

В русском обычно выделяют для изучения грамматики одно сослагательное наклонение (помимо очевидных изъяснительного и повелительного).

Все остальное рассматривается как вторичные понятия (даже как семантические дериваты), и изучают их уже в академических курсах.

Что вам-то нужно? Если хотите все до мелочей понять (что сомнительно на таком уровне), изучите хотя бы по корпусной грамматике.

http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Там много спорного, но хотя бы некоторая систематика имеется.

.----------------

> 'm confused потому что иногда читаю, что "условное РАНьШЕ называлось
>   сосл.накл." (получается это одно и то же наклонение?), а другие
>   источники рассматривают его абсолютно отдельно

Тут действительно путаница в терминологии. Это недоразумение, следствие упрощений для школьников и иностранцев. Авторы используют разные системы описания грамматик. Возникает путаница. И она усугубляется тем что под наклонением при изучении иностранных языков часто действительно смешивают грамматическую форму и категорию, ей выражаемую.

Попробую объяснить. Прежде всего, надо смотреть, какой терминологической системы придерживается автор.

Дело в том, что исходное, индоевропейское сослагательное наклонение, служащее для выражения *возможного или необходимого будущего*, сохранилось во многих романских (наверное, и в испанском), но полностью утрачено в русском языке, его заменило будущее время. А *условное* частично сохранилось.

Давайте мы с вами будем использовать следующую систему понятий (кстати, эта фраза сама по себе - один из способов выражения ***предлагательного наклонения*** или слабого императива, которого вообще нет в русских учебных грамматиках).

Сослагательное (modus subjunctivus) - выражающее возможное будущее
Условное нереальное (modus conjunctivus) - выражающее невозможное (обычно - прошедшее)
Условное реальное (modus conditionalis) - выражающее возможную ситуацию-условие.
Желательное (modus optativus) - выражающий желание

С первыми двумя действительно основательная путаница, их часто не разделяют, а если и разделяют, то путают названия. если объединяют, то все вместе называют сослагательным наклонением.

Раньше (в школе!) считалось, что есть только одно наклонение, сослагательное, которое служит для выражения всех четырем семантических условий, но в первую очередь - условного. Это единое наклонение и называли сослагательным. Когда поняли, что такой подход даже для школы не совсем правильным, условное наклонение выделили в самостоятельное, условное. Осюда и недоразумения. ***Если все-таки не разделять коньюнктивус и субъюнктивус, то правильно будет сказать, что одна грамматическая форма (сослагательного или условного наклонения) обслуживает три семантических понятия: сослагательное, условное, желательное*** наклонения. Но при обучении школьников и иностранцев так глубоко обычно не копают.

Если в деталях ничего не напутал, то так. Я не специалист, могу сейчас только общую картину передать.

Comment: обоснуйте свой ответ! На основании чего вы считаете, что можно выделять эти наклонения?

Comment: @Серж смените, пожалуйста, тон и формулировку. "Обоснование" у меня в тексте. Если оно вам не нравится, объясните почему. У меня есть сильное подозрение, что автор путает понятия, но это не для вас информация, мне нужно ответ от него получить, чтобы продолжить разговор.

Answer (score 1):

Наклонение - основной способ выражения модальности, т.е. отношения к действительности(реальная и ирреальная действительность). Реальная - изъявительное наклонение, ирреальная - повелительное и условное/сослагательное.Модальность - свойство предложения, но нет основания строить теорию наклонения целиком на синтаксической основе, надо изучать наклонение и как чисто морфологическую категорию, хотя с учётом её синтаксической роли. При изучении наклонений в современном русском языке необходимо ставить 3 вопроса: Как строятся формы наклонения морфологически(как образуются),что они выражают (грамматич. значение)как они употребляются.

Что касается самого термина "сослагательное наклонение", то он введен в науку М. Смотрицким (1619 г.)и является калькой лат. conjunctivus (modus), где conjunctivus <сослагательный>, <соединительный>, от conjungere <соединять, сочетать>, из con- <со->, <вместе> и jungere <связывать>,от jugum <ярмо, узы> ; modus- - <способ, наклонение>. Для калькирования лат. conjunctivus использованы: прист. со-<вместе>, основа слога- глаг. слагать <соединять, прибавлять>, собств. <класть (положить) рядом, вместе> и суф. -тельн-. Таким образом, термин сослагательное наклонение буквально значит <соединительное, связывающее>. Название отражает те случаи, когда формы сослагательного наклонения глаг. употребляются в придаточных предложениях и <связываются> (соотносятся) с глаг. главного предложения. А это и есть условное наклонение.

У Мелетия Смотрицкого были наклонения изъявительное, сослагательное, повелительное, он признавал и ещё два(было до него)- желательное и неопределённое (инфинитив).Забракованное Ломоносовым желательное наклонение почти не упоминается в последующих грамматиках до К. С. Аксакова и Ф. И. Буслаева. В последнее время акад. А. А. Шахматов реставрирует и обновляет термин желательное наклонение. Под влиянием грамматик западноевропейских языков, преимущественно французского, в русских грамматиках с конца XVIII в. появляется и условное наклонение(conditionnel).

Что у нас есть **сегодня**?Традиционный термин "сослагательное наклонение" очень удобен, охватывает все значения, принят в АН, хотя в "Грамматике р.я." в скобках дан термин"условное", а некоторые учёные называют его условно-желательным, встречается в научной литературе и термин "ирреально-гипотетическое" наклонение.

**Значение и употребление.**  Формы сослагательного (в школе - условного) наклонения глагола обозначают желательное или возможное действие при каких-либо условиях или действие, в котором говорящий сомневается и только предполагает его.

Буланин Л. Л. выделяет три основных оттенка сослагательного наклонения:

1. Оттенок желательности.

Я волком бы выгрыз бюрократизм. (В. В. Маяковский)

2. Оттенок условного, возможного действия.

"Неужто ты влюблён в меньшую?"—"А что?"— "Я выбрал бы другую,   Когда б я был, как ты, поэт".   (А. С. Пушкин)

3. Оттенок опасения, сомнения, предположения.   Боюсь: брусничная вода
   Мне не наделала б вреда.(А. С. Пушкин)

Он рыбачил тридцать лет и три года  И не слыхивал, чтоб рыба говорила.  (А. С. Пушкин)

Так что морфологически  условное и сослагательное наклонение можно употреблять по выбору, а вот желательное вошло в сослагательное/условное.
И это правильно. Можно увидеть смысловую разницу между: (1) "пошел бы ты в баню" (что-то вроде пожелания) и (2) "если бы ты пошел в баню, ты бы попарился" (условие), однако эта семантическая разница не выражается формально (форма одна - пошёл бы) следовательно, лежит за пределами морфологии, значит, эти формы представляют собой одно морфологическое наклонение. Но ср. "поди в баню" - значение "пожелания" выражено другой формой, чем в примере (1), значит, перед нами разные грамматические категории - условное/сослагательное и повелительное наклонения.